# playbackstopped not raised -Naudio

Tags: naudio

I just want to display the messagebox inside the audioOutput_PlaybackStopped. Anybody can help? I used Naudio.

Here is my code:

```
public void playRecordedUser()
        {

            pcm = new WaveChannel32(new WaveFileReader(@"D:\2.wav"));
            //.PadWithZeroes = false;
           reductionStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
            waveOutDevice = new DirectSoundOut();
            waveOutDevice.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(audioOutput_PlaybackStopped);
            waveOutDevice.Init(reductionStream);
            waveOutDevice.Play();
           // pcm.Close();
           // waveOutDevice.Dispose();
        }

        void audioOutput_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hey");
            waveOutDevice.Stop();
            reductionStream.Close();
            waveOutDevice.Dispose();
            waveOutDevice = null;
            pcm.Close();
        }
```

Comment: this is a lot more complicated than you need. Just use an AudioFileReader. Don't use the BlockAlignReductionStream at all.

Comment: how to use that? sorry im just new in using NAudio. thanks to your answer :)

Comment: my problem is i cant record again with my code. it says that @"D:\2.wav" is being used by another process. i just want to stop what ever process is that so i tried using playback stopped. but still wont work.

Comment: As I said. Don't use the BlockAlignReductionStream or WaveChannel32, just use AudioFileReader, and dispose it when you're done.

Comment: thaaanks a lot. it worked. :) i still had the same error but this time  the problem is within waveviewer where i also access the same filename. may i know if there is a way to know if the waveviewer is already done displaying waveforms so i can dispose or stop this process?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `WaveChannel32` continues to return data past the end of the stream you supply, so the output continues to play forever.

Instead of your current `WaveFileReader` -> `WaveChannel32` -> `BlockAlignReductionStream` chain, try `WaveFileReader` -> `BlockAlignReductionStream` -> `Wave16ToFloatProvider` like this:

```
var reduce = new BlockAlignReductionStream(new WaveFileReader(@"D:\2.wav"));
var provider = new Wave16ToFloatProvider(reduce);

waveOutDevice = new DirectSoundOut();
waveOutDevice.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(audioOutput_PlaybackStopped);
waveOutDevice.Init(provider);
waveOutDevice.Play();
```

This will play to the end of the wave file then signal end of playback.

Don't forget to Dispose the `reduce` object after playback completes.

Comment: it worked. the message box already displays when i stop recording but the problem is. after recording my program displays waveform using a waveviewer and when i tried your code, the waveform displaying is just a flat vertical line. and i got the same error when i tried recording again. that @"D:\2.wav" is being used by another process. actually this is the problem that i wanted to solve thats why i tried using playbackstopped. please help me in this matter. i badly need help. thanks :)

Comment: Instead of calling `Close` on the reduction stream, call `Dispose`.  Disposing the object will definitely close the source stream, but `Close` may not.  I haven't tested.